# "Flooded" islands in converted OSM data

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I'm having a problem with "flooded" islands when converting OSM natural=water data to shapefiles and opening it in qgis. It doesn't happen consistently; as you can see from the attached screenshot, some islands are fine, but others initially show up, then get covered by the parent water polygon.

Here's how I'm generating my data:

```
osmconvert north-america-latest.osm.pbf -b=-80,40,-70,50 --complete-ways --complex-ways -o=w080n40.o5m
osmfilter w080n40.o5m --keep= --keep-ways="natural=water" --keep-relations="natural=water" -o=water.osm
ogr2ogr -skipfailures -f 'ESRI Shapefile' water water.osm
```

Then I open the resulting polygon layer in qgis, with the result illustrated.

[image: Illustration of "flooded" islands in qgis]

Comment: If you only keep ways and relations with `natural=water`, you might miss islands of different landuse that are inner rings in water multipolygons.

Comment: Thanks, Andrej. I'll try that and see if it helps. I was thinking in terms of holes in traditional layers.

Comment: Yes, that solved it—thanks! Still getting my head into the OSM mindset. If you'd like to repost that as an answer, @AndreJ, I'll accept it.

Comment: If you solved it, you can answer your own question with the command line that worked for you.

Comment: No problem, Andre. I was hoping to give you credit, but if that's not a big deal, I'll copy the answer there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @AndreJ for the final answer. It turns out that it's a bad idea to try to filter by attribute *value* using osmfilter; instead, just filter by attribute *key,* then do the per-value filtering in qgis. That way, relations and ways stay together.  Example:

```
osmfilter w080n40.o5m --keep= --keep-nodes="natural=" --keep-ways="natural=" --keep-relations="natural=" -o=natural.osm
```

Then add qgis filter to the layer with natural='water'

Comment: Hi Canuck - You may want to accept your own answer so that others can see that your question has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks, @Cyrus . Unfortunately, the site makes me wait 2 days before accepting my own answer, but I will do it tomorrow when the cooling-off period expires.